# Wordpress huge database size

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with below plugins:

- wp-types
- seo by yost

I have only 21000 post from my custom post type but my database size is 353 MB.

My biggest table is:

- post table: 21165 Records => 189.6 MB
- post meta table: 199593 Records => 120.6 MB

I also try using wp-optimize but database size wasn't changed.

Why my database is huge??

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: 353 MB isn't that big. It's big because you have a lot of data on your WordPress website? Is there a problem with it being that size?

Comment: It's only text data. I don't know why being this size. I have only 21165 posts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not huge. A database for a Wordpress running WooCommerce with less than 100k products is more than a gig.

What you have to do is to clean orphans that are probably wasting space in the wp_postmeta table.

Run this SQL to check if you have those lines:
select * from wp_postmeta where post_id NOT IN (select ID from wp_posts)